# When I click on a uitableview cell the text for that cell gets bolder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I click on a uitableview cell the text for that cell gets bolder. What can I do?

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIView * selected = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    [selected setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 234/255.0f green: 234/255.0f  blue: 234/255.0f alpha: 1.0]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selected;

    NSDictionary * val = [self.entries objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    UIView * cellview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 85)];
    [cellview setBackgroundColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];

    NSString * namet = @"";
    NSString * pitcht = @"";
    NSString * category = @"";
    NSString * first_name = @"";
    NSString * last_name = @"";
    NSString * photo = @"";

    NSDictionary * investor;
    NSDictionary * startup;
    float miles = 0;

    NSDictionary * user;

    if(showInvestors)
    {
        if ([val objectForKey: @"investor"] &&
            [val objectForKey: @"investor"]!= (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            investor = [val objectForKey: @"investor"];

            if ([investor objectForKey: @"user"] &&
                [investor objectForKey: @"user"] != (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                user = [investor objectForKey: @"user"];

                first_name = [user objectForKey: @"first_name"];
                last_name = [user objectForKey: @"last_name"];

                namet = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", first_name, last_name];
            }

            if ([investor objectForKey: @"bio"] &&
                [investor objectForKey: @"bio"] != (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                pitcht = [investor objectForKey: @"bio"];
            }

            if ([investor objectForKey: @"category_list"] &&
                [investor objectForKey: @"category_list"] != (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                category =  [investor objectForKey: @"category_list"];
            }


            if ([investor objectForKey: @"photo_url"] &&
                [investor objectForKey: @"photo_url"] != (id)[NSNull null])
            {
                photo =  [investor objectForKey: @"photo_url"];
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {

        if ([val objectForKey: @"startup"] &&
            [val objectForKey: @"startup"] != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            startup = [val objectForKey: @"startup"];
        }


        if ([startup objectForKey: @"name"] &&
            [startup objectForKey: @"name"] != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            namet = [startup objectForKey: @"name"];
        }


        if ([startup objectForKey: @"pitch"] &&
            [startup objectForKey: @"pitch"] != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            pitcht = [startup objectForKey: @"pitch"];
        }

        if ([startup objectForKey: @"categories"] &&
            [startup objectForKey: @"categories"]  != (id)[NSNull null] &&
            [[[startup objectForKey: @"categories"] objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"name"] &&
            [[[startup objectForKey: @"categories"] objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"name"] != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            category = [[[startup objectForKey: @"categories"] objectAtIndex: 0] objectForKey: @"name"];
        }

        if ([startup objectForKey: @"photo_url"] &&
            [startup objectForKey: @"photo_url"] != (id)[NSNull null])
        {
            photo =  [investor objectForKey: @"photo_url"];
        }
    }


    UIImageView * midview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 15, 50, 50)];

    if(photo.length >= 1)
    {
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: photo];
        [midview setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"]];
        [midview.image imageCroppedToFitSize: CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
    }
    [cellview addSubview: midview];

    UILabel * name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(70, 15, 150, 16)];
    [name setText: namet];
    [name setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 16.0f]];
    [name setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0/255.0f green: 79.0/255.0f blue: 79.0/255.0f alpha: 1.0]];

    UILabel * pitch = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(70, 31, 200, 26)];
    [pitch setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
    [pitch setText:  pitcht];
    pitch.numberOfLines = 1;
    [pitch setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0/255.0f green: 79.0/255.0f blue: 79.0/255.0f alpha: 1.0]];

    UIImage * play = [UIImage imageNamed: @"e_play.png"];
    UIImageView * playview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: play];
    [playview setFrame: CGRectMake(280, 20, play.size.width, play.size.height)];
    [cellview addSubview: name];
    [cellview addSubview: pitch];
    [cellview addSubview: playview];

    NSString * catstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Industry: %@", category];
    UILabel * catlb = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(70, 58, 180, 14)];
    [catlb setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
    [catlb setText:  catstr];
    [catlb setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0/255.0f green: 79.0/255.0f blue: 79.0/255.0f alpha: 1.0]];
    [cellview addSubview: catlb];


    if ([val objectForKey: @"latitude"] &&
        [val objectForKey: @"latitude"] != (id)[NSNull null] &&
        [val objectForKey: @"longitude"] &&
        [val objectForKey: @"longitude"] != (id)[NSNull null])
    {

        CLLocationDegrees slatitude = [[val objectForKey: @"latitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees slongitude = [[val objectForKey: @"longitude"] doubleValue];

        CLLocationDistance distance = [self myDistanceFromLatitude: slatitude longitude: slongitude];

        if(distance > 0)
        {
            miles = [self convertToMiles: distance];
        }
    }

    NSString * distancetxt = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.1f miles", miles];

    UILabel * dislb = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(220, 15, 50, 16)];
    [dislb setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 11.0f]];
    [dislb setText:  distancetxt];
    [dislb sizeToFit];
    [dislb setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 79.0/255.0f green: 79.0/255.0f blue: 79.0/255.0f alpha: 1.0]];
    [cellview addSubview: dislb];


    [cell addSubview: cellview];

    return cell;
```

That's my code above for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

When I click on a cell, the text for the cell get sharper....

What can I do?

How do I make it so that when I select a cell it does not get bolder or sharper? thanks.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexpath method What happen in there?

Comment: The reason seems to be that all the UI in your cell is recreated when your select it. You need to check if the UI controls is nil and then create it or not based on that... If I have understod your question right? Or do you want to set the text to bold?

Answer (score 1):

Each time your cells get repainted, you add UILabels (and image views). This is not what you want. Yiu want set the text on existing labels — but you stack labels on top of each other.

You should create a custom UITableViewCell subclass.

As you describe that touching increases the font size, I assume you do `[tableview reloadData]`; in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like This.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)index
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]; 
}
```

Comment: the text is not in textLabel though. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make subclassing of the UITableViewCell and override method

```
- (void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected
            animated: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super setSelected: selected
              animated: animated];

    if (selected)
    {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14.0];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0];
    }

}
```